# Using Xamarin Storyboard Editor to edit XIBs

Tags: xamarin.ios, storyboard, xib, xamarin

Just wanted to know if it is possible to open regular XIB files from new Xamarin's storyboard editor? Switching back and forth between Xamarin and Xcode is a bit inconvenient, and the new editor looks really nice; however, Storyboards have a few drawbacks and it is a pain to use them for our projects.

Any ideas re availability of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plan is to add support for editing .sib files in future versions of Xamarin Studio.This will likely not happen in time for the first release with the iOS Designer (i.e. version 4.2), but I think it would be reasonable to expect that version 4.4 will have support for editing .xib files.

Comment: I guess my question is pretty predictable, but... Any ideas re timeline for this? :)

Comment: I suspect sometime this fall (I don't think it'll be a lot of additional work), but I can't guarantee that. The iOS Designer should be out by the end of the summer afaik.

Answer (score 1):

As of right now, no. I think it might be because of the complexity of the underlying XML but I'm not 100% sure. You can always create or upvote it on uservoice: http://xamarin.uservoice.com/forums/144858-xamarin-suggestions/suggestions/2700302-a-monotouch-xib-editor.

Answer (score 0):

Using stand-along Xib files is now available, you can learn how to do it here -

[Using Xamarin Storyboard Editor to edit XIBs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591131/using-xamarin-storyboard-editor-to-edit-xibs)